# find formula for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

shouldn't the particular solution work in the original equation? before I even add the general solution with constants solved?

$$y''+3y'+2y=e^{-t}$$ 
with $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=0$

**1. use method of parameters**

**2. use method of undetermined coefficients**

$$r^2+3r+2 = 0$$
$(r = -2)$ $(r = -1)$

**(1.)**

$$y(t)=ve^{-2t}+we^{-t}$$
$$...$$
$$ve^{-2t}+we^{-t}=0$$
$$-2v'e^{-2t}-w'e^{-t}=e^{-t}$$
$$...$$
$$v' = -e^t$$
$$w' = 1$$
$$...$$
$$v = -e^t$$
$$w=t$$
$$...$$
then
$$y(t)=(-e^t)(e^{-2t})+(t)(e^{-t})$$
$$y_g(t)=c_1e^{-2t}+c_2e^{-t}+(-e^t)(e^{-2t})+(t)(e^{-t})$$

but when I plug in y(t) and its derivatives on the left I don't get $e^{-t}$ ? What am I doing wrong?

**(2.)**
$$r^2+3r+2 = 0$$
$(r = -2)$ $(r = -1)$

$(s=1)$ since the roots -2, and -1 solve the auxiliary equation.

since $e^{-t}=Ct^me^{rt}$
then $m=0$

equation has form: $t^1(A)e^{-t}$

$y_p(t)= Ate^{-t}$

$y_p'(t)=Ae^{-t}-Ate^{-t}$

$y_p''(t)=-2Ae^{-t}+Ate^{-t}$

$...$

$y''_p(t) + 3y'_p(t) + 2yp_(2)=e^{-t}$

$(-2Ae^{-t}+Ate^{-t}) +3(Ae^{-t}-Ate^{-t}) + 2(Ate^{-t}) = e^{-t}$

$A=1$
then
$$y_p(t)= te^{-t}$$
is a solution but plugging into the equation is inconsistent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint.

The solution is the sum of the solution of the homogeneous equation that you have found:
$$
y=c_1e^{-2t}+c_2e^{-t}
$$
and a particular solution that, you can easily see, is $y=te^{-t}$

than find the constants by initial conditions.

---

To find the particular solution use the method of undetermined coefficients for $y=ate^{-t}$

$$
y'=ae^{-t}-ate^{-t} \qquad y''=-ae^{-t}-ae^{-t}+ate^{-t}
$$
substituting in the given equation:
$$
-2ae^{-t}+ate^{-t}+3ae^{-t}-3ate^{-t}+2ate^{-t}=e^{-t} \Rightarrow ae^{-t}=e^{-t} \Rightarrow a=1
$$

Comment: but shouldn't the particular solution work in the original equation? before I even add the general solution with constants solved?

Comment: I've add to my answer.

Comment: nevermind I got it. thanks